# A test to ascertain that both equation lies on the same line

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What tests can you devised to ascertain that two equations 
$ax+by=c$ and $rx+sy=t$ define the same line?
(assume the coefficients a,b,r,s are all non-zero)

Putting this into linear combinations of column vectors we have

$x\begin{bmatrix}
a\\ 
r
\end{bmatrix}
+y\begin{bmatrix}
b\\ 
s
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
c\\ 
t
\end{bmatrix}$

This is the $\operatorname{Span}\left \{ \vec{\alpha_{1}},\vec{\alpha_{2}} \right \}=\vec{b}$

Indeed, if two equations lies on the same line, they must be parallel to each other and each can be expressed as a linear combination of the other.

I think it might require linear dependence for me to go further. Could someone give me a **hint**?

Comment: This happens iff one equation is a nonzero multiple of the other, $r/a=s/b=t/c.$

Comment: It is just as simple as @symplectomorphic's comment pointed out. If you do want to use matrix, the statement is $\text{rank} \begin{pmatrix}a&b\\r&s\end{pmatrix}=\text{rank} \begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\r&s&t\end{pmatrix}=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint if they represent the same line then $a.l=r,b.l=s,c.l=t$ where $l$ is a constant thus $\frac{a}{r}=\frac{b}{s}=\frac{c}{t}=constant$ this is called test of consistency of a line and the system is called consistent system